# Android: ContentObserver selfChange

Tags: android

In the ContentObserver class, the method onChange is passed a boolean selfChange that's defined as: *"true if the update was caused by a call to commit on the cursor that is being observed."*

What's the proper way to update the cursor so that selfChange is set to true? My current code doesn't reference the cursor at all for an update and selfChange is always false as a result.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("date", date.getTime());
getContentResolver().update(URI, values, "_id = " + id, null);
```

Comment: I too would like some clarification on what would and wouldn't cause selfChange to be true.  It seems to be taken for granted in documentation but I'm having a hard time figuring out what affects it.

Answer (score 8):

The Android framework does not provide a way to do this through the static `ContentResolver#update()` method.

**Explanation**

When `ContentResolver#notifyChange(Uri,ContentObserver)` is called with the `ContentObserver` object as the observer that initiated the change, that `ContentObserver` will have `onChange()` called with `selfChange` set to true

From the docs:

> void android.content.ContentResolver.notifyChange(Uri uri, ContentObserver observer)
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> **uri** The uri of the content that was changed.
>
> **observer** The
>   observer that originated the change, may be null. The observer that
>   originated the change will only receive the notification if it has
>   requested to receive self-change notifications by implementing
>   ContentObserver.deliverSelfNotifications() to return true.

So if you're calling `notifyChange()` from within your `ContentProvider` update/insert/delete methods which are in turn being called from the `ContentResolver` update/insert/delete methods, you won't have the `ContentObserver` reference to pass to `notifyChange()` and so won't have `selfChange` set to true.

**Workaround**

This will work if the ContentProvider is in the same process as the client code. It requires a custom ContentProvider and a more complex/error prone calling of the update/insert/delete methods.

We can create custom methods in our derived `ContentProvider` that take a `ContentObserver` as a parameter. For example, if we wanted to have the `update()` method call `notifyChange()` with the `ContentObserver` we would do something like:

```
public class MyContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, 
                String[] selectionArgs) {
        // Just call our new method with 'null' as the ContentObserver
        update(uri,values,selection,selectionArgs,null);
    }

    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, 
                String[] selectionArgs, ContentObserver changeOriginator){
        // Do the update
        ...
        // Notify the change with the ContentObserver that wants to ignore it
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,changeOriginator);
}
```

To use the new method, you'll have to get the `ContentProvider` object from the `ContentResolver` and call our new `update()` method:

```
ContentProvider cP = getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(URI).getLocalContentProvider();
MyContentProvider mCP = (MyContentProvider)cP;
mCP.update(URI, values, "_id = " + id, null, contentProvider);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue. 
It seems you have a customized ContentProvider.

Please take a look at your implementation of your method: `ContentProvider.update(Uri uri, ContentValues cv, String selection, String[] selectionArgs);`

My guess is you have `getContext.getContentResolver.notifyChange(Uri uri, ContentValues cv)` implemented in your customized update method, which notify ContentProvider everytime it's called, and ContentObserver receives the notification, and in turn calls the update method. 
So the infinite loop forms.

Also, [my life with android](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/03/observing-content.html) has a very detail yet clear explanation on how it works fully.

Hope it helps!

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Hey I faced the same problem. Did your onChange() method works fine? You must just call what you want to do inside the onChange() method scope.

That's what I did, and it worked fine! It notify when some change occurs to the cursor.

Comment: Thanks for the response :)

I moved all my code out of helper methods and directly into the onChange method, but still the selfChange flag is always false. Do you have any other ideas as to what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: I think doesnt matter if it returns false. What matters is if the code reach the onChange() method, if enters the onChange() method, thats cause he detected some change. Mine returns false too, and its ok. I does its job in the onChange() method. So check if the code enters the onChange() method, if yes, then its ok, put there what you want it to do in case of some changing. Put a Log message inside the onChange() method for checking if it reaches the method.

Comment: The onChange method is being called successfully. The problem that I am facing is that my onChange code changes the cursor, which then fires the onChange method again (and again, and again...). I've implemented a workaround to avoid the infinite calling loop, but from my understanding, selfChange is supposed to be true when my cursor causes the change. This would allow me to put all my code inside of if (!selfChange) { ... } instead of keeping track of last changed IDs and such.

Comment: That I was. I thinking too I thought that the selfChange should be true, but it is false, and the onChange() method would just be called when it was true. But it returns false and onChange() method is just called when something changes on the content provider its observing. For me works fine. But if it works fine for you its ok.